# What does the "application" tag mean (and what should it mean)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that questions labeled with the **application** tag generally fall into the category of applications for a course of study or fellowship.  However, a few (I think two currently) use this tag to mean the application of theory to do something "useful", often leading to a marketable product.  My tendency would be to create a tag called **application of theory** or something similar for the second type.  However, I also realize that the term *application* is ambiguous, so I'd like to slightly rename it to avoid the confusion.  One possibility is *application process*, but that seems only slightly better.

So now, my question. I haven't done much retagging before, is this something I should just do, or are there more guidelines I'm missing?  Second, does anyone have better suggestions than *application process* and *application of theory*?

Comment: Tag wiki is created to mean applications for a course of study or fellowship http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/application/info

Answer (score 1):

By default, I understand **application** as in "application for a position". I'd be rather in favor of leaving the tag application with this meaning, and to change it for when it means **application of theory** to something like "applied-research".

I guess that if you have the correct privileges, you can do create the new tag and retag the required posts. If there is a conflict later on, we can solve it here :)