# The application tag

Tags: discussion, tags

In the post [What does the “application” tag mean (and what should it mean)?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/169/4394) a brief exchange indicates that the [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) tag should concern applications for, for example, jobs (as opposed to applying something). The tag at the time of writing this has been applied to 89 posts. A relatively new tag has appeared, [faculty-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faculty-application) (currently on four posts). I can see that there are two ways to go here, to either use the [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) tag as a base and adding tags such as [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research), [faculty](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faculty) and [graduate-school](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-school) to narrow down the scope of [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) or to accept "hybrid" tags such as [faculty-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faculty-application). I would opt for the former but what would be preferable. With only four tagged posts it would be easy to make the change.

I see this also reflecting on how the tags are built and used in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single tag should have one primary purpose. However, there are enough similarities between different kinds of applications that it seems to me unwise to have completely separate tags for each different kind of application.

What I would recommend is "linking" the subsidiary tags as "synonyms" of the application tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think and have previously proposed that [application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) should be a synonym of [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions). This has no up votes on the [synonyms](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page, so maybe other disagree, but then again it has no down votes either. I also think that [faculty-application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faculty-application) is a synonym of [job-search](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-search).

Comment: I think that there are many formal and style issues that overlap between different types of applications and therefore think that a general 'application' tag has a purpose.